# How to randomly choose sample points that maximize space occupation?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I would like to generate the sample points that can randomly fill/cover a space (like in the attached image). I think they have a method called "Quasi-random" that can generate such sample points. However, it's a little bit far from my knowledge. Can someone make suggestions or help me find a library that can be do this? Or suggest how to start writing such a program?

[image: Sample points cover the space]

*In the image, 256 sample points are applied on the given space, placed at random positions to cover the whole given space.*

Update:
I just try to use some code from [Halton Quasi-random Sequence](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/halton/halton.html) and compare with the result of pseudo-random which is post by friend below. The result of Halton's method is more better in my opinion. I would like to share some result as below;

[image: Pseudo-random and Halton's sequence]

The code which I wrote is

```
#include "halton.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
int main()
{
    int m_dim_num = 2;
    int m_n = 50;
    int m_seed[2], m_leap[2], m_base[2];
    double m_r[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < m_dim_num; i++)
    {
        m_seed[i] = 0;
        m_leap[i] = 1;
        m_base[i] = 2+i;
    }

    cv::Mat out(100, 100, CV_8UC1);
    i4_to_halton_sequence( m_dim_num, m_n, 0, m_seed, m_leap, m_base, m_r);

    int displaced = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i=i+2)
    {
        cv::circle(out, cv::Point2d((m_r[i])*displaced, (m_r[i+1])*displaced), 1, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, 8, 0);
    }
    cv::imshow("test", out);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

As I little bit familiar with OpenCV, I wrote this code by plot on the matrix of OpenCV (Mat). The "i4_to_halton_sequence()" is the function from the library that I mentioned above.

The result is not better, but might be use in somehow for my work. Someone have another idea?

Comment: @acheong87 thank you for improve my grammar.

Comment: Your example image has a lot of symmetry - is that something you need from the solution?

Comment: your example is exactly Sobol sequence.  did you get it from wikipedia?

Comment: @thang I get this picture from other source, however that website link from Wikipedia again :p

Comment: @JasonD I just need the points are random in arbitrary cover all the area of the space. The image is just the example which is make it easy to explain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am going to give an answer that will seem half-assed.  However, this topic has been studied extensively in the literature, so I will just refer you to some summaries from Wikipedia and other places online.

What you want is also called low-discrepancy sequence (or quasi-random, as you pointed out).  You can read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence.  It's useful for a number of things, which includes numerical integration and, more recently, simulating retinal ganglion mosaic.

There are many ways to generate low-discrepancy sequences (or pseudo quasi random sequences :p).  Some of these are in ACM Collected Algorithms (http://www.netlib.org/toms/index.html).

The most common of which, I think, is called Sobol sequence (algorithm 659 from the ACM thing).  You can get some details on this here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobol_sequence

For the most part, unless you are really into it, that stuff looks pretty scary.  For quick result, I would use GNU's GSL (GNU Scientific Library): http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/

This library includes code to generate quasi-random sequences (http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Quasi_002dRandom-Sequences.html) including Sobol sequence (http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Quasi_002drandom-number-generator-examples.html).

If you're still stuck, I can paste some code here, but you're better off digging into GSL.

Comment: I dont know about gcc and I use MS Window, I will try the GSL after I find the ways to install it. :)

Comment: I'm curious as to why OP had the [image from the wiki article on Sobol sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sobol_sequence_2D.svg) if he didn't already know about them..

Comment: also GSL is open source.  You can rip those functions right out of the library without having to deal with gcc or any of the gnu stuff: gsl_qrng_niederreiter_2,  gsl_qrng_sobol,  gsl_qrng_halton, and gsl_qrng_reversehalton.

Answer (score 3):

Well here's another way to do quasi-random that covers the entire space.

Since you have 256 points to use, you can start by plotting those points as a 16x16 grid.

Then apply some function that give some random offset to each point (say 0 to ±2 to the points' x and y coordinates).

Answer (score 0):

You could create equidistant points (all points have same distance to their neighbors) and then, in a second step, move each point randomly a bit so that they appear 'random'.

The second idea I have is:
1. Start with one area.
2. Create a random point P rand about the 'middle' of your area.
3. Divide the area into 4 areas by that point. P is the upper right corner of the lower left subarea, the upper left corner of the lower right area and so on.
4. Repeat steps 2..4 for all 4 sub areas. Of course, not forever, but until you're satisfied.

This algorithms ensures that each 'hole' (i.e. the new sub area) is filled with a point.

Update: Your initial area should be twice as large as your area, because of step (2). This ensures having points at the edges and corners as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a ["low discrepancy sequence"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence). The linked Wikipage explains how you can generate them.

But I suspect you already knew this, as your image is very similar to the [2,3 Halton sequence example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halton_sequence) from Wikipedia

Comment: Note that in some cases, a hardcore distribution with a suitable disk radius can work (I am not saying it would be better).

Comment: @MSalters yes, I knew this is Halton sequence image as I mentioned above. But, my point is to implementation step is little bit difficult for me. And I need some help? :)

Answer (score -3):

You just need library rand() function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

unsigned int N = 256; //number of points
int RANGE_X = 100; //x range to put sample points in
int RANGE_Y = 100;

void PutSamplePoint(int x, int y)
{
   //some your code putting sample point on field
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0)); //initialize random generator - uses current time as seed
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        int x = rand() % RANGE_X; //returns random value in range [0, RANGE_X)
        int y = rand() % RANGE_Y;
        PutSamplePoint(x, y);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @FominArseniy, thank you for your code. However, by the method that you provide its seem like the points are not cover the whole block (100x100). The points are randomly but, still empty in some area of the block.

Comment: This is just plain wrong. The question asks for something completely different from just plain pseudo-random points.

Comment: In defense of @FominArseniy, it's not actually immediately clear what the asker meant. Also keep in mind that FominArseniy answered this question before I improved the question's grammar. I can see the question being interpreted as filling the space with random points (but letting statistics fill the "whole" space). Yes, this would seem a much less challenging question, but we can't assume the asker's expertise here.